# returned object is undefined in a custom ajax service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I created an AngularJS service which does ajax request to the server and returns the response object to the controller. Below is my service

```
   app.factory('ajaxService', function() {
   return {
        ajaxcall: function(url, type, data, handler) {
            $.ajax({
              url: url,
              type: type,
              data: data,
              beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-OCTOBER-REQUEST-HANDLER", handler);
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
              }
            })
            .done(function(response) { 
                console.log("ajaxService done: ");
                console.log(response);
                return response;
            })
            .fail(function(response) {
                console.log("in onCheckUser-error: ajaxService ");  
            });

        }
   }
});
```

The controller is defined as below

```
var app = angular.module('starter', [])

app.controller('myCtrl', function(ajaxService) {
var res = {};
res = ajaxService.ajaxcall("https://www.travelmg.in/check-login",'POST','',"onCheckLogin");
console.log(res);
});
```

Here, i get the expected response in console in the ajaxService service. When i return the response, i see an "undefined" value in res variable in console.

I don't understand why the res variable is undefined. Please suggest

Comment: Is there a reason why you use `$.ajax` instead of `$http`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because your making an asynchronous call, which means it will not return the result immediately.

only way to resolve this is to receive the promise object returned from `$.ajax` & use the `.done()` function on it to receive the successful data.

**What you need to do:**

- Move the `done()` & `fail()` outside service factory.
- return the ajax promise object all the way to the consumer, i.e controller.

**JS CODE:**

```
//service factory code
return {
    ajaxcall: function(url, type, data, handler) {
        return $.ajax({
          url: url,
          type: type,
          data: data,
          beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-OCTOBER-REQUEST-HANDLER", handler);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
          }
        });
   }
 }

//controller code
app.controller('myCtrl', function(ajaxService) {
   var res = {};
   ajaxService.ajaxcall("https://www.travelmg.in/check-   login",'POST','',"onCheckLogin")
    .done(function(response) { 
          console.log("ajaxService done: ");
          console.log(response);
          //return response; // dont return instead process the result here
     })
     .fail(function(response) {
          console.log("in onCheckUser-error: ajaxService ");  
     });
});
```

**Note:**

- I would personally dont prefer mixing `jquery` and `angularjs` library unless `jquery` is really needed for some third party library. both are two different frameworks with different ideology,so dont mix them.
- also if your referring to `jquery` only for `$.ajax` api ? then i would suggest you to use `$http`, whose API is same as `$.ajax`. ref: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: @dremweiver: thanks for your reply, however i have tried the method you suggested. I receive and error as : "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'done' of undefined"

Comment: can you check if your returning promise object from jquery ajax , `return $.ajax({`

Comment: @Dev-One: using $http service worked too after adding return keyword.

Comment: @gauravbhand : do refer the note  added above.

Answer (score 0):

You have built the application in angular so it would be convenient to use `$http` directive to make ajax calls. Inject `$http` is your service, then you can handle the response as such:

```
ajaxService.ajaxcall("https://www.travelmg.in/check-login",'POST','',"onCheckLogin").then(function(response) { 
   console.log(response.data);
});
```

Comment: Hello @Dev-One, I am using some extra headers in my ajax request, but not sure how to add them using $http service.

Comment: i referred the above doc, and implemented my ajax request with $http service. I get the valid response in console in when i include .then function in the ajaxService service. But when i try to move the .then function in to the controller, i get the same error as "controllers.js:37 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"